# Help to understand the grammar and meaning of a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

I don't understand the grammar and meaning of this sentence.

> To say that I was moved to tears just doesn't do this act service.

What does 'do this act service' mean?

The whole context:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sentence was recast and the word "service" was replaced by ** justice**, I think the meaning would be more apparent.

To say that I was moved to tears doesn't **do justice to this act**.

Better would be: To say that I was moved to tears doesn't **do this act justice**.

> From [Cambridge online](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/do-justice-to-sb-sth): to treat someone or something in a way that is fair and shows their or its true qualities:
>
> > This postcard doesn't do justice to the wonderful scenery.

Comment: Thanks! Will 'do service to'== 'do justice to'? Are they interchangeable?

Comment: Hmmm. Again, I feel you'd need to recast the sentence for the word "service" to fit.  See: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/do%20(someone)%20a%20service You could say " To say that I was moved to tears just doesn't convey the service of this act."And I don't feel it conveys what is trying to be said either.

Comment: So, you feel the original phrase " do this act service" make no sense?